# Loop in switch or switch in loop

Tags: php

I was wondering which code is effective. Notice, that `$type = 1` is same during the whole loop.

```
if(!$handle = opendir('.')) {
    return false;
}

$result = array();
while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if(!$resDir = self::getUrlByType($type, $entry)){
        continue;   
    }

    switch($type) {
        case 1:
            /* do something */
            break;

        case 2:
            /* do something different */
            break;
    }
}
closedir($handle);
```

I think, that these both codes should be proceesed with same duration, because it is only one condition there.

```
if(!$handle = opendir('.')) {
    return false;
}

switch($type) {
    case 1:
        $result = array();
        while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if(!$resDir = self::getUrlByType($type, $entry)){
                continue;   
            }

            /* do something */
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        $result = array();
        while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if(!$resDir = self::getUrlByType($type, $entry)){
                continue;   
            }

            /* do something different */
        }
        break;
}


closedir($handle);
```

I made negative microtime footprint at the begining of each script `$time = -microtime(true);` and the difference between current microtime `$time += microtime(true);` at the end of script. After i displayed the results `echo "Time: ", sprintf('%f', $time), "\n";` i saw these values:

Time of first script was average between `0.0084` and `0.0203`.

The secon results were much different, average between `0.0062` and `0.0072`.

My question is, what is the case of this behaviour? Why didnt PHP compiler cashed that?

This ist the PHP output:

```
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Time: 0.000103
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Type: 1
Time: 0.000065
```

Comment: because PHP is not a compiled language?

Comment: I'm sure you ran this thousands of times to get an average (infinitesimal) time for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop inside a switch would be preferred, in my opinion. There can be a case where it may make more sense one way or the other so this depends on the scenario.

But on a logistical stand point, having a loop inside of a switch means you only have to check for one condition and loop through a lot of "known" process. While if you loop a switch it constantly checks a state then does one process of known code just to repeat itself with a bit more overheard.